# AngularJS - Form validation except fields that only have the "required" rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, angularjs, validation

I know with a form, I can get the $valid property to check whether the entire form is valid.  Is there a way to get the validity of a form but ignore undirtied fields whose only rule is "required"?

I have a form that has a save button and a next button.  This form is part of a series of forms.  When the user clicks on save, I want full validation, but if the user clicks on "next", I want it to validate (and alert the user) for all fields except those who have no validation rules on them other than the "required" flag.  This is so that I can save a partially completed form without having to alert the user to the missing fields until later (because they will want to save progress on their forms without having to complete them altogether).

Perhaps there's a way to get the fields with a jQuery selector/filter of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand the question and your use case, but it somewhat sounds like you may need to use custom form validation.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

(you may need to scroll down a bit when first loading the link)

Basically you may need to add your own custom directive to control the validity of the inputs you have in mind.

Alternatively, and maybe not quite the "Angular" way, you can avoid using the data binding between the fields and model, effectively opting out of Angular validation.  Obviously losing the data binding may be a bigger issue for you but you *could* get at those values with code outside of your Angular stack.

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully clarify the use case.  Does that help?  (and thanks for the reply, btw)